# asp.net forms authentication + jquery get requests

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Let us say the user is successfully 'cookie asp.net form authenticated'. (S)he can now perform a get request via action A of controller B. Let us say this returns HTML to the user's browser. This HTML contains some jquery code that performs a GET request to a action that also requires authentication (e.g. after the user hits a button). Is the jquery GET request automatically authenticated as the user is logged in and has a cookie? Hope this makes sense.

If not, what is the best way to check, if the request was a ajax one during the authentication/authorisation (e.g. in a filter attribute). Thanks!

Comment: you want to create a custom authorization filter for ajax calls

Comment: Thanks. So you reckon the answer is no and I need to detect whether the request is an ajax request in my filter attribute. Please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: To be more clear, Yes, **you SHOULD authenticate the request**. Even though the user is posting, he could have forged the request from outside your site. I hesitate to post an answer b/c you can take 2 approaches. You create a custom authorization filter and apply it to your ajax action method. Or you can check for **isloggedin** in you action filter. In both cases, if the user does not have authorization, your return JSon false. Or you return a custom error code.

Comment: Sorry you confuse me. The user is logged in (i.e. cookie created). The question is whether the ajax request 'appears' to be logged in as well. Let us ignore forgery for now. I am just looking at GET requests and just authentication - ignoring authorisation for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APS.NET Forms authentication uses a cookie like most any web authentication.

The cookie will be tied to the domain your requesting.

So ajax or regular request are all just HTTP requests (usually GET or POST) all requests to the server (depending on http headers) will include the cookie as part of the request.

How you implement the security on the server side is up to you.

Comment: This is in disagreement with Dave. Can you please provide some references - I did not find much - otherwise I would not have asked here. Thanks.

Comment: there is actually no disagreement. we are in effect saying the same thing. Only one answer is necessary.